# Save a binary VB file (including RDW) from non-zOS file system, as a binary VB file in zOS without adding new RDW

Tags: ftp, zos

I have downloaded a VB binary file from zOS, with RDWs but without BDW.

When I try to send it back it treats the existing RDW as part of the data and adds new RDW.

Is there a known way to do it, except editing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching the ftp transfer mode to *block mode* should do what you want:

```
quote mode b
```

You may, or may not need the `quote` prefix, depending on your ftp client.
Also, since you want the data set on z/OS to be `RECFM=VB`, you might need to tell the FTP server:

```
quote site recfm=vb lrecl=nnn
```

Where *nnn* is the maximum record length plus 4.

Comment: It didn't solved the problem and behaved the same

Comment: @Avi Would you edit your question and add a hex dump of the first two to three records, please. This might give me a hint what's wrong.